# Event after login

Tags: acumatica

Is there any event I can hook into to show/display a message after the user has logged in ? Like welcome screen with a short message from the company. And the user needs to click a button before proceeding. Otherwise, it's back to the login screen.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an event which triggers on log-in. Perhaps another approach might be for you to modify the Login.aspx so that you show this message before the user logs-in. I am not sure whether modifying this page is fully supported by Acumatica however. The Login.aspx is located in the Frames folder of the site.